# JSON to Array c#

Tags: c#, json, type-conversion

I Have a JSON with this values

```
{"interface":"ALL",
 "dv":"1",
 "alarms":[{"Id":0,
            "Type":"URL",
            "Trigger":"facebook",
            "Output":"video"},
           {"Id":1,
            "Type":"URL",
            "Trigger":"twitter",
            "Output":"video"},
           {"Id":2,
            "Type":"URL",
            "Trigger":"ebay",
            "Output":"video"}
]}
```

And i would like parse this information to mi C# Code

I do  this for Strings tags and works ok

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
String value =(String) obj["dv"];
```

but i have an error for tag Array alarms. I've tried with:

```
Array value = null;
value =(Array) obj["alarm"];
```

but i get an error (Message=Can not convert Array to byte array. Source=Newtonsoft.Json).

Comment: try to map this json object to a datacontract , you can use [link](http://json2csharp.com/) to make the class you can use as datacontract.

this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be helpful in doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try convert your `alarms` into a [JArray](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm):

```
JArray value = null;
value = obj["alarms"] as JArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JavaScriptSerializer` for this.
For example:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Json.Net

```
JArray value = null;
value = obj["alarms"] as JArray;
```

The casting should be JArray

Answer (score -2):

Your json string has a reserved c# keyword: `interface`. Try changing this and see if it works.